# Mysql total elapsed times from two dates

Tags: mysql

If i have two rows

```
id created          start            stop
1  28-01-2011 23:00 28-01-2011 23:00 28-01-2011 23:01  
2  28-01-2011 23:10 28-01-2011 23:10 28-01-2011 23:11
```

What query can i run to get the total elapsed time for one date, so for 28-01-2011 the total time was 2 minutes.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do those columns have type `datetime` or are they strings in this format: 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm'?

Comment: column type: timestamp. @MarkByers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well one option is straight forward:

```
select sum(unix_timestamp(stop) - 
    unix_timestamp(start))/60 from table
    where date(created) = '28-01-2011';

mysql> select now(), date_add(now(), interval 10 minute);
+---------------------+-------------------------------------+
| now()               | date_add(now(), interval 10 minute) |
+---------------------+-------------------------------------+
| 2011-10-04 13:29:56 | 2011-10-04 13:39:56                 |
+---------------------+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select sum(unix_timestamp(now()) -
          unix_timestamp(date_add(now(), interval 10 minute)));
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| sum(unix_timestamp(now()) - unix_timestamp(date_add(now(), interval 10 minute))) |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                             -600 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select sum(unix_timestamp(now()) - 
          unix_timestamp(date_add(now(), interval 10 minute))) / 60 ;
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| sum(unix_timestamp(now()) - unix_timestamp(date_add(now(), interval 10 minute))) / 60 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                              -10.0000 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I have not. I have added hint that will help. Just did some testing and see results above.

Comment: You have to use `date(created) = '2011-01-28'`, not `'28-01-2011'`.

Comment: But consider "28-01-2011 23:00" - this is unusual format to begin with. yeah, date (create) would not work at all for this format.

Comment: He said that the field is a timestamp so I guess this is only how the data is formatted for output.

Comment: yeah, if so then just date(created) = '2011-01-28' and it will rock.

Comment: Yes, please edit your answer. You can add the `created >= '2011-01-28' and created < '2011-01-29'` variation (which will use the index of `created` if possible).